# Detecting if certain conditions are true and executing further actions if they are true

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game for a class and I am trying to make a function that detects if the main hero of the game is within the bounds defined by the method, then it will check a series of if's and execute them if at any point they become true.

```
initHitbox(hero,100,200,300,400);

function initHitbox(object1, leftBound, rightBound, topBound, botBound){
    //left boundary
    if(object1.y > topBound &&
       object1.y < botBound &&
       object1.x > leftBound &&
       object1.x < rightBound){
           console.log("YOU ARE IN THE BOX");
           if(object1.x < leftBound){
               object1.x = leftBound;
           }
           if(object1.x > rightBound){
               object1.x = rightBound;
           }
           if(object1.y > botBound){
               object1.y = botBound;
           }
           if(object1.y < topBound){
               object1.y = topBound;
           }
       }
    else{
        console.log("YOU ARE NOT IN THE BOX");
        null;
    }
}
```

In the above code, it can always detect if the main hero character I have in the canvas is within the parameters I defined using the console logs (always displays "YOU ARE NOT IN THE BOX" or "YOU ARE IN THE BOX"), but the method will not execute anything beneath that.

TLDR: Want object to be trapped in box, isn't trapped in box, but is detected in the box.

Comment: what is this `null` keyword in `else` block

Comment: the conditions after the in message are never true, because of the previous check.

Comment: Still new to coding, but I believed that by putting that there if, the if statement wasn't true then it just wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Instead of "null", you should write "return;" if you want to prevent further execution of the function.

Comment: A jsfiddle would really help out in finding the problem.

Comment: Aside from the logging, it really seem like you want to take those inner four `if` statements and move them out, and then just get rid of the outer `if/else`. If you want to log when going outside the box, then have all four of those `if` statements set a shared boolean variable, and check to see if it was set after those four execute.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat unclear from the question but I am guessing that you want your player to be confined to the specified box. If the player is outside of the box you want to "reset" the player and position them back within the box?

If this the case then simply move the 4 if statements to the else block:

```js
initHitbox(hero,100,200,300,400);

function initHitbox(object1, leftBound, rightBound, topBound, botBound){
    //left boundary
    if(object1.y > topBound && object1.y < botBound && object1.x > leftBound && object1.x < rightBound){
    console.log("YOU ARE IN THE BOX");
 }
    else{
        console.log("YOU ARE NOT IN THE BOX");
  
  // Move player back into the box by reseting the player's position
  if(object1.x < leftBound){
     object1.x = leftBound;
  }
  if(object1.x > rightBound){
     object1.x = rightBound;
  }
  if(object1.y > botBound){
     object1.y = botBound;
  }
  if(object1.y < topBound){
     object1.y = topBound;
  }
    }
}
```